# "Makefile Tool" VS Extension - How to Set Current Directory as Makefile path?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, makefile, gnu

I would like to start using the "[Makefile Tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/)" VS Code extension. In order to enable the extension, I need to set the makefile path AKA the path to the makefile of the project; however, my makefiles are in different directories.

Is there a way to set "makefile Path" to my current directory or something similar that would allow me to use the tool? Heres is what my settings.json looks like:

```
{
"workbench.layoutControl.enabled": true,
"workbench.layoutControl.type": "toggles",
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [

],
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
"workbench.tree.indent": 30,
"makefile.loggingLevel": "Verbose",
"terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
"terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
"terminal.integrated.defaultLocation": "terminal",
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace",
"editor.fontFamily": "Ubuntu Mono",
"C_Cpp.experimentalFeatures": "Enabled",
"window.title": "File Name: '${activeEditorLong}' | Path:  ${folderPath}    | Status: ${dirty}",
"makefile.launchConfigurations": [

],
"makefile.makefilePath":
"material-icon-theme.folders.color": "#F1D592",
"makefile.panel.visibility": true,
"interactiveWindow.alwaysScrollOnNewCell": }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "Makefile Tools" extension [does not yet support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues/90) multi root workspaces; however, there is a workaround.

> you could try wrapping all the entry point makefiles of all your
> different workspaces into a top level makefile, like this:

```
 all:
 
 
     $(MAKE) -C ./folder1/project1/ <...>

     $(MAKE) -C ./folder2/project2/ <...>
```